# Does gcc's STL support rvalue references now?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, std, libstdc++

I know Visual Studio 2010's standard library has been rewritten to support rvalue references, which boosts its performance considerably.

Does the standard library implementation of gcc 4.4 (and above) support rvalue references?

Comment: "STL" is the Standard Template Library; most of it was adopted by the 1998 C++ standard, and some of its techniques were later applied to other components such as iostreams and strings.  Today, some people incorrectly refer to the whole C++ Standard Library (the "stdlib") or to its full complement of templates as "the STL". See http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/95/HPL-95-11.html and http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/

Comment: @Roger: well it is standard, and it does use templates, and it is a library. why do we nitpick this stuff.

Comment: @Inverse: No, it is not all standard, only most of it was adopted.  In addition, I believe the OP does not mean to exclude the parts of the stdlib that didn't come from the STL.

Comment: It would be good if the OP could comment on their selection of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this from the STL of gcc 4.4 :

```
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
  _Vector_base(_Vector_base&& __x)
  : _M_impl(__x._M_get_Tp_allocator())
  {
    this->_M_impl._M_start = __x._M_impl._M_start;
    this->_M_impl._M_finish = __x._M_impl._M_finish;
    this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage = __x._M_impl._M_end_of_storage;
    __x._M_impl._M_start = 0;
    __x._M_impl._M_finish = 0;
    __x._M_impl._M_end_of_storage = 0;
  }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

[GCC supports rvalue references](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).  Unfortunately, [the libstc++ page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) doesn't say if the library implementation takes advantage of that.